# When to use useMemo and useCallback for performance optimization?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usecallback, react-usememo

Consider i got such example:

```js
import React, { useMemo, useCallback } from 'react'

const Hello = (props) => {
  const { firstName, lastName } = props
  const fullName = useMemo(() => `${firstName} ${lastName}`, [firstName, lastName])

  const sayHello = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(`Hello, ${fullName}`)
  }, [fullName])

  return (
    // ...
  )
}

export default Hello
```

Basically i have a component called `Hello`, and it receives two props `firstName` and `lastName`, then i need to calculate `fullName` based on those two props and has a function `sayHello()` uses `fullName` to do something

So my question is: In here is it necessary to use `useMemo()` and `useCallback()` for performance optimization? It seems like its kind of overuse of `useMemo()` and `useCallback()` for just a little benefit, and i am not sure if this might cause potential side effects?

Comment: What uses `sayHello`? That makes a big difference to the answer.

Comment: I think generally it is recommended to just write normal functions, and only when you find there is an issue with performance, reach for the memoization tools. As T.J. states, it depends on what consumes `sayHello`.

Comment: As Crowder stated; what if you pass `sayHello` to a list of many items and it's used onClick? Passing a newly created event handler on every render will cause virtual dom compare to fail and React will repaint all the items to DOM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In that example, different answers for that use of `useMemo` and that use of `useCallback`:

- The `useMemo` is almost certainly overkill; it's just not that expensive for `sayHello` to build that string (vs. creating a new function to pass to `useMemo` on every render).
- The answer for `useCallback` depends on how `sayHello` is used. If `sayHello` is supplied as a prop to a component that is memoized on that prop (like a [`PureComponent`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent), something that implements [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) directly, or the result of wrapping a component with [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo)), it can be a performance optimization to keep `sayHello` stable by memoizing it as you've shown so that the component(s) you're passing it to don't have to re-render when it changes. If not, though, it's probably not useful, no.

I agree with [Drew Reese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65020098/when-to-use-usememo-and-usecallback-for-performance-optimization/65020238#comment114950870_65020098): Start simple by just writing your functions, and then apply optimization to code you see performing poorly. (Although there are some situations where you might be proactive based on previous experience — say, passing a callback you could memoize to a couple of hundred pure child components...)

Comment: Note that if I do `<ListItem key={item.id} onClick={callbackWithUseCallback} item={item} />` Even if `ListItem` is not pure (React.memo, PureComponent, shouldComponentUpdate) when `item` does not change the jsx is re created but virtual dom compare will have React **not** re render the DOM. If you do `onClick={()=>'new ref created'}` then even if ListItem is pure it will re create jsx and re render DOM because virtual DOM compare will fail (the event handler has a new reference).

Comment: @HMR - "render" in this context means the component function runs again (the component's `render` function if it's a `class` component), which is what we're trying to avoid. (And yes, "`render`" was arguably not the best name for that method.) That way you don't have the overhead of running the component's function / `render` method and the overhead of the virtual DOM comparison. It's true that the DOM isn't updated if nothing changes even if the component isn't pure, it's just more work to get there if it isn't. :-)